# Cómo puedo cambiar el color de los bordes de un JTextField cuando recibe el foco?

Tags: java, java-swing, jtextfield

Mi idea es cambiar el color de los bordes de los JTextField cuando reciben el foco, pero no me está funcionando y no encuentro solución.
Le puse un listener al JTextField para que cuando reciba o pierda el foco cambie la variable "color" de la clase NormalBorder, y esta clase tiene el método paintBorder que utiliza ese color para pintar el borde, pero no funciona, el borde sigue con el mismo color... A continuación dejo el código de prueba.

Clase principal:

```
public class Test extends JFrame {
private JButton enter;
private AccountField accountField;

public Test(){
    enter = new JButton("Enter");
    accountField = new AccountField();
    
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(250, 250);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setBackground(Color.white);
    setLayout(null);
    add(enter);
    add(accountField);
    
    accountField.setLocation(250/2 - accountField.getWidth()/2, 250/2 - accountField.getHeight());
    enter.setSize(100,30);
    enter.setLocation(accountField.getX() + enter.getWidth()/2, accountField.getY() + accountField.getHeight() + 5);
    
    setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       new Test();
   }
}
```

Código de la clase AccountField:

```
public class AccountField extends JTextField {
private NormalBorder border;

public AccountField() {
    border = new NormalBorder(new Color(219, 219, 219), 0, 10, 0, 10);
    
    setBorder(border);
    setSize(200, 38);
    addFocusListener(new Listener(border));
}
```

}

Código de la clase Listener:

```
public class Listener implements FocusListener {
   private Color color1 = Color.red;
   private Color color2 = Color.blue;
   private NormalBorder border;

   public Listener(NormalBorder border) {
       this.border=border;
   }    

   @Override
   public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
       System.out.println("gain");
       border.setColor(color1);
   }

   @Override
   public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
       System.out.println("lost");
       border.setColor(color2);
   }    
}
```

Código de la clase NormalBorder:

```
public class NormalBorder implements Border {
   private Color color;
   public Insets insets;

   public NormalBorder(Color color, int top, int left, int bottom, int right) {
       this.color = color;
       this.insets = new Insets(top, left, bottom, right);
   }

   @Override
   public void paintBorder(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
       g.setColor(color);
       g.drawRect(x, y, width-1, height-1);
   }

   @Override
   public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c) {
       return this.insets;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean isBorderOpaque() {
       return false;
   }

   public void setColor(Color color) {
      this.color = color;
   }
}
```

Ya he comprobado que si cambian las variables color de la clase NormalBorder, y el método paintBorder también recibe correctamente el color... alguien sabe qué podría hacer para solucionarlo, o de qué otra forma debería hacerlo?

Comment: tu pregunta puede ser cerrada por tres cosas y dos motivos: la primera es que solamente dices que no funciona, la segunda es que no pones el código de tu main donde llamas tus clases ( es decir no tienes un [mcve] ) y tercero en que tu código funciona así que no se puede reproducir el problema que tienes con la información que provees

Comment: @RuslanLópez estoy usando más clases, y es engorroso tener que pasarlo todo

Comment: Entonces voto por cerrar tu pregunta por el motivo : Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [mcve]

Comment: @RuslanLópez modifiqué el post, está bien ahora?

Comment: cuales son los imports de `AccountField` ?

Comment: @RuslanLópez import java.awt.Color; y import javax.swing.JTextField;  No importa NormalBorder ni Listener porque están en el mismo paquete

Comment: y los pusiste asi? o pusiste java.awt.*?

Comment: @RuslanLópez lo puse así

Answer (score 0):

Mi teoria es que en alguno de los archivos tienes el *import* incorrecto, asi que renombrando tu clase Listener y con un poco de ayuda de netebans para le layout nos queda:

### JBorderFocus (antes test)

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class JBorderFocus extends JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form JBorderFocus
     */
    public JBorderFocus() {
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        enter = new JButton();
        accountField = new AccountField();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBackground(Color.white);
        setSize(250,250);

        enter.setText("Enter");
        getContentPane().add(enter, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        getContentPane().add(accountField, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JBorderFocus.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new JBorderFocus().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private AccountField accountField;
    private JButton enter;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

### MyFocusListener (antes Listener)

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;

public class MyFocusListener implements FocusListener {

    private Color color1 = Color.red;
    private Color color2 = Color.blue;
    private NormalBorder border;

    public MyFocusListener(NormalBorder border) {
        this.border = border;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
        border.setColor(color1);
    }

    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
        border.setColor(color2);
    }
}
```

### AccountField

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class AccountField extends JTextField {

    private NormalBorder border;

    /**
     * Creates new form AccountField
     */
    public AccountField() {
        border = new NormalBorder(new Color(219, 219, 219), 0, 10, 0, 10);
        initComponents();
        setSize(200, 38);
        addFocusListener(new MyFocusListener(border));
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        setBorder(border);
    }// </editor-fold>                        


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si te fijas en el código de `setBorder` puedes ver que al establecer el borde tiene que hacer un repaint para reflejar los cambios.

En tu código, el primer repaint funciona (el repaint del setBorder) y te muestra el borde con el color de inicio, pero luego no se realiza ninguna operación de repintado sobre el componente, por lo que no puedes ver cambios al momento de perder o ganar el foco.

Lo que quiero decir es que para que se vean los cambios, tiene que haber un repintado sobre el componente. Una prueba de esto es que si al mismo código que has pasado en la pregunta, lo inicias estando con el foco en el field, luego aprietas el botón y redimencionas la pantalla, veras reflejado el cambio del color correctamente, ya que al redimensionar la pantalla los componentes se tienen que volver a pintar.

Básicamente en el código del borde tienes que llamar al método de repintado del componente:

```
g.setColor(color);
g.drawRect(x, y, width-1, height-1);
c.repaint();
```

Si lo pruebas, eso es todo, funcionara como quieres.

Ahora, en términos de rendimiento, esto no es para nada eficiente,
si bien veras que todo funciona como debería, al menos en mi computadora
el CPU se dispara consumiendo bastante apenas empieces a interactuar con el campo de texto.

Lo que tienes que hacer para optimizarlo, es una referencia hacia el componente que
tiene el borde (esto se saca del parámetro).

Luego, en el método donde estableces el nuevo color `setColor`, debes comprobar si se ha creado la referencia y ahí repintar el componente.

```
public class NormalBorder implements Border {

    private Component c;

    private Color color;
    private Insets insets;

    public NormalBorder(Color color, int top, int left, int bottom, int right) {
        this.color = color;
        this.insets = new Insets(top, left, bottom, right);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintBorder(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        if (this.c == null) {
            this.c = c;
        }

        g.setColor(color);

        g.drawRect(x, y, width - 1, height - 1);
    }

    @Override
    public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c) {
        return insets;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isBorderOpaque() {
        return false;
    }

    public void setColor(Color color) {
        if (c != null) {
            c.repaint();
        }
        this.color = color;
    }

}
```

Eso ademas de reflejar los cambios porque el `Listener` llama al método `setColor`, también mejorara el rendimiento, ya que no se repinta siempre, si no que solo cuando se cambia el valor del color.